# How to use SQL to query a csv file with Scala?

Tags: sql, scala, file, apache-spark

I am new to Spark Scala and I am trying to make a SQL query on a csv file and return the records.  Below is what I have, but is not working:

```
val file = sc.textFile(“file:///data/home_data.csv”)
val records = file.sqlContext("SELECT id FROM home_data WHERE yr_built < 1979")
combined.collect().foreach(records)
```

I get errors with the `file.sqlContext` function.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508054/spark-sql-how-to-read-a-tsv-or-csv-file-into-dataframe-and-apply-a-custom-sche

Comment: will you provide the error in question

Comment: Check the answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Can you use class to map the data with the respective field names and datatypes, then use your query:

```
case class Person(first_name:String,last_name: String,age:Int)
val pmap = p.map ( line => line.split (","))
val personRDD = pmap.map ( p => Person (p(0), p(1), p(2). toInt))
val personDF = personRDD. toDF
```

then query the persondf.

I dont know the schema, so i formulated this way.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your response.  Basically, I am just looking to  query on a CSV with SQL and show the results.  Can you help please?
   Trying to do something like this:    val file = sc.textFile(“file:///data/home_data.csv”)
val records = file.sql("SELECT id FROM data_table WHERE size < 100")
records.show