# Read TSV file in pyspark

Tags: python, file, apache-spark, pyspark

What is the best way to read .tsv file with header in pyspark and store it in a spark data frame.

I am trying to use "spark.read.options" and "spark.read.csv" commands however no luck.

Thanks.

Regards,
Jit

Comment: Hi JKD, welcome to SO! Please read up on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next one. Happy coding!

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508054/spark-sql-how-to-read-a-tsv-or-csv-file-into-dataframe-and-apply-a-custom-sche?rq=1

Comment: @Ehsan Do we have to create a schema always (as it involves opening the file in local machine) ? Can't we use the header column as column names?

Comment: up to my knowledge I think schema is needed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well you can directly read the tsv file without providing external schema if there is header available as:

```
df = spark.read.csv(path, sep=r'\t', header=True).select('col1','col2')
```

Since spark is lazily evaluated it'll read only selected columns.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this – it worked for me:

```
#Read tsv file 
df = spark.read\
    .format("csv")\
        .options(inferSchema = "True",header = "True", sep = "\t" )\
            .load(path)
display(df)
```