# Simple TSV file - can't figure our import serde

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a fairly simple (but very large) compressed text file on s3 and want to read it into Glue/Athena.   Its tab delimited (TSV) but I can't seem to find a crawler, or an AThena query or hive setup that will read this simple file.

Here are the snippets of the records:
(first line is bytes, second is decoded string)

```
[b'0\taaa.11111\t1\n', b'1\taaa.aa\t1\n', b'2\taaa.aaa\t4\n', b'3\taaa.aaaa\t1\n', b'4\taaa.aaaaaa\t1\n', b'5\taaa.aaaaaaa\t1\n', b'6\taaa.aaaaaaaa\t1\n', b'7\taaa.aaaaaaaaa\t1\n']
['0\taaa.11111\t1\n', '1\taaa.aa\t1\n', '2\taaa.aaa\t4\n', '3\taaa.aaaa\t1\n', '4\taaa.aaaaaa\t1\n', '5\taaa.aaaaaaa\t1\n', '6\taaa.aaaaaaaa\t1\n', '7\taaa.aaaaaaaaa\t1\n']
```

The Ahena DDL I've use:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `edge4`(
  `id` bigint, 
  `domain` string,
  'num_hosts' bigint
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escape.delim'='\\') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://commoncrawl/projects/hyperlinkgraph/cc-main-2023-may-sep-nov/domain'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1705429326', 
  'write.compression'='GZIP')
```

Comment: You can use spark for this, directly in your glue script, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799363/read-tsv-file-in-pyspark)

Comment: @Bogdan I ran into trouble with spark because these are unsplittable gzip files and are very large.  Apparently spark doesn’t parallelize reading gzip.  for some reason, Athena seems to deal with them better.  So was trying to get them into glue catalog so that I can join, filter, and process them into smaller parquet files.

Comment: @Bogdan right here.  Fastest path is spark.read.csv with save as table option.  Also, need to download and decompress first as spark cant parallel process a single gzip as it is unsplittable.