# How to read a csv with using the schema

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I am trying to load a csv file in a pyspark dataframe using:

```
spark.read.options(delimiter=';', header=True).csv(file)
```

But I get the following error

```
AnalysisException: 'Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.;'
```

I try to insert the schema manually but it still doesn´t load any value

```
customSchema = StructType([
    StructField("aaa", StringType(), True),
    StructField("bbb", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("ccc", IntegerType(), True)])


spark.read.option('header', 'true').option('delimiter', ';').schema(customSchema).csv(file)


spark.read.load(file, format="csv", header="true", sep=';', schema=customSchema)
```

I only get an empty dataframe with columns name

Comment: Can you show sample rows of your input file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark-SQL : How to read a TSV or CSV file into dataframe and apply a custom schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508054/spark-sql-how-to-read-a-tsv-or-csv-file-into-dataframe-and-apply-a-custom-sche)

Comment: Can you show some sample input ?

Answer (score 0):

For a CSV file delimited like the following.

```
aaa;bbb;ccc
john;12;14
peter;3;7
sally;8;27
```

You can read this into pyspark like so.

```
from pyspark.sql import types

customSchema = types.StructType([
    types.StructField("aaa", types.StringType(), True),
    types.StructField("bbb", types.IntegerType(), True),
    types.StructField("ccc", types.IntegerType(), True)])

df = spark.read.options(delimiter=';', header=True).csv(inputs, schema=customSchema)
```